# Python pip not working for scipy, scikit-learn and gensim

Tags: windows-7, pip, python-3.3, gensim

I'm trying to install `scipy`, `scikit-learn`, and `gensim` on Windows 7 with Python 3.3.
If I try any of these:
pip install sci

```
pip install scipy
pip install scikit-learn
pip install gensim
```

I end up with an ImportError similar to:

```
ImportError: no module named numpy
```

And yes, I have installed `numpy` - it works fine if I try to import it in Python. I've managed to install `scipy` and `scikit-learn` by downloading executable installers, but `gensim` doesn't have one...
I've also tried using `easy_install` for all three, but that doesn't work either.

Is it something to do with the Python installation? Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you try to use pip3 ?

Comment: @Traklon Yes, but it tells me it's not recognized as a command...

Comment: I have the same problem except with mac....

Comment: For gensim -- Use the link to download tar.gz file https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/gensim/gensim-0.10.2.tar.gz#md5=678f0e294238c98c81118e61470035c8 , use
 tar.gz file,once downloaded tar.gz file , extract it and then run `pip setup.py test` and then run `pip setup.py install` on command prompt, then try importing gensim using `import gensim`